# display the row with the first and last odd number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

good day everyone . I've been searching for a long time for the activity that our professor wants us to do .

for example my column name is `tax`, `tax` has these values:

```
 TAX
-----
3681
4292
4895
1894
1127
```

the program should show numbers 3681 and 1127 . any response is much appreciated . btw our school is using MS SQL Server 2000 .

Comment: Sounds like a HW question to me... Can you show us some examples that you may have tried? What specifically are you having problems with? We help you debug and solve your query question, but we will not write it for you without you showing some sort of try yourself :)

Comment: Using what logic do you conclude that 3681 and 1127 are the 'first and last odd numbers'? If only considering the last digit then sgeddes has it, if that's a mistake and you really want the first and last as in lowest and highest then my answer has that. If you mean first and last from your unordered list, that's a different matter.

Comment: Nice to hear that your school is keeping things up to date. SQL Server 2000 has fallen out of even *extended* support by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(tax), Max(tax) 
FROM Table
WHERE tax %2 <> 0
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06b3f/2/0)

If you actually want first and last from your unordered list, it's a trickier proposition and results could be inconsistent, since without a value to ORDER BY you can't guarantee order. Would usually use ROW_NUMBER(), but not available in 2000, if that's what you're after there are options, the easiest would be to do:

```
SELECT Tax, IDENTITY(1,1) as TaxID
INTO Table2
FROM Table1

SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 Tax FROM Table2 WHERE Tax %2 <> 0 ORDER BY TaxID)
      ,(SELECT TOP 1 Tax FROM Table2 WHERE Tax %2 <> 0 ORDER BY TaxID DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question, you are looking for the rows with the lowest or highest odd number as the last character?  If so, then this should work:

```
select t.tax
from yourtable t
  join (
    select min(right(tax,1)) minoddchar, max(right(tax,1)) maxoddchar
    from yourtable
    where tax % 2 = 1 --ensure odd result
    ) t2 on right(t.tax,1) in (t2.minoddchar, t2.maxoddchar)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f5ad/5)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
SELECT tax FROM Table ORDER BY tax.id ASC LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT tax FROM Table ORDER BY tax.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

or this:

```
SELECT MIN(tax.id), tax FROM Table
UNION
SELECT MAX(tax.id), tax FROM Table
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select tax from Table fetch first 1 row only;
select tax from table fetch last 1 row only;
```

Comment: oh, got it. changing my answer